# Java Scanner not completely reading each line in a .txt

Tags: java, file

This program is attempting to separate a text file into words and then count each time each word is used. The scanner seems to be only reading parts of each line, and I have no idea why. This is my first time using this scanning method.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class WordStats {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>(1);
        ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<>(1);
        Scanner sc2 = null;
        try {
            sc2 = new Scanner(new File("source.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }
        while (sc2.hasNextLine()) {
            Scanner s2 = new Scanner(sc2.nextLine());
            boolean set=false;
            while (s2.hasNext()) {
                num.add(1);
                String s = s2.next().replaceAll("[^A-Za-z ]", " ").toLowerCase().trim();
                for(int i=0;i<words.size(); i++){
                    if(s.equals(words.get(i))){
                        num.set(i,num.get(i)+1);
                        set=true;
                    }
                }
                if(!set){
                words.add(s);
                num.add(1);
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<words.size();i++){
            System.out.println(words.get(i)+" "+num.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

the text file is the Gettysburg Address:

> ABRAHAM LINCOLN, “GETTYSBURG ADDRESS” (19 NOVEMBER 1863)
>
> Fourscore and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this
>   continent, a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the
>   proposition that all men are created equal.
>
> Now we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation,
>   or any nation so conceived and so dedicated, can long endure. We are
>   met on a great battle-field of that war. We have come to dedicate a
>   portion of that field, as a final resting place for those who here
>   gave their lives that that nation might live. It is altogether fitting
>   and proper that we should do this.
>
> But, in a larger sense, we can not dedicate-we consecrate-we can not
>   hallow-this ground. The brave men, living and dead, who struggled
>   here, have consecrated it, far above our poor power to add or detract.
>   The world will little note, nor long remember what we say here, but it
>   can never forget what they did here. It is for us the living, rather,
>   to be dedicated here to the unfinished work which they who fought here
>   have thus far so nobly advanced. It is rather for us to be here
>   dedicated to the great task remaining before us-that from these
>   honored dead we take increased devotion to that cause for which they
>   gave the last full measure of devotion-that we here highly resolve
>   that these dead shall not have died in vain-that this nation, under
>   God, shall have a new birth of freedom-and that government of the
>   people, by the people, for the people shall not perish from the earth.

the original line breaks are preserved.
my output seems to only count only part of each line, and also counts whitespace as a word twice.
output:

```
abraham 1
lincoln 1
gettysburg 1
address 1
 2
november 1
fourscore 1
and 5
seven 1
years 1
ago 1
our 2
fathers 1
brought 1
forth 1
on 2
this 3
continent 1
a 7
new 2
nation 5
conceived 2
in 4
liberty 1
now 1
we 8
are 2
engaged 1
but 2
```

It could be something other than the scanning method, but I'm more familiar with that part of the code and I don't think that is it.

Comment: Consider using a HashMap<String, Integer> of word -> count to maintain this count instead of two ArrayLists? This may or may not be your error but it will certainly make the problem cleaner.

Comment: I would have used a hashmap, except this was a class assignment and we haven't formally learned maps yet. I'm sure I could figure it out, but I'm more comfortable with arraylists anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset your boolean set at the beginning of this while loop

```
 while (s2.hasNext()) {
 set = false;
```

once you encounter your first repeated word in each line, set is always true and no new words are being added to your list.

And the whitespace count is because of how your replaceall handles the  "(19" and "1863)" since there are no alphabetical characters in those "words".

Comment: I haven't checked the word count, but now it's running to the end. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your code unconditionally adds `1` to the `num` list on each iteration of the loop. This shifts `num`s in relation to `words`, producing wrong output.

Removing `num.add(1);` from the nested `while` loop would fix the problem. However, a better approach would be making a `Map<String,Integer>` to track counts. In addition to ensuring that counts and words would always be in a synchronized state, this change would let you remove the nested `while` loop altogether, and use fast lookup based on your map's algorithm.

Comment: word counts seem to be correct.  A map would probably be a better choice, but there is no problem with is approach.

Comment: @Justin No, they have no chance of being correct for non-empty files. Check the size of `num` and `words`, the `num` will always have more items.

Comment: note that all the counts in the list are correct.  Also note that the only time an element is being added to num, an element is also being added to words.  This ensures that both the words and num lists are the same exact size.

Comment: @Justin Incorrect programs sometimes produce results that look correct. Unconditional addition of `1` to `num` is incorrect behavior, because it breaks the relationship between `num` and `words` lists as "parallel arrays" (rarely a good thing to use in high-level programming languages).

Comment: @Justin "Also note that the only time an element is being added to num, an element is also being added to words" That's demonstrably wrong: there are two, not one, call of `num.add(1);`.

Comment: oops, i see it now, you are correct.  But while the code is poorly done, it does not effect the output at all.  You could add 1 to nums a million times before starting the while loops and the number counts would still be correct, but it would obviously be inefficient.  The way to correct his missing words in the output is because he does not reset his set boolean to false.

Answer (score 1):

The logic is a bit skewed. You have parallel lists that should have the same number of elements, but are not added in parallel.

```
    Map<String, Integer> wordFrequencies = new TreeMap<>();

    while (sc2.hasNextLine()) {
        Scanner s2 = new Scanner(sc2.nextLine());
        while (s2.hasNext()) {
            String word = s2.next().replaceAll("[^A-Za-z ]", " ")
                .toLowerCase().trim();
            Integer n = wordFrequencies.get(word);
            wordFrequencies.put(word, n == null ? 1 : 1 + n);
        }
    }
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : wordFrequencies.entrySet()) {
        System.out.printf("%-40s %5d%n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
```